# VK Сообщества: как отправить сообщение с фотографией?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api, соцсети

Мне нужно отправить сообщение от имени сообщества с вложением фото. Чтобы это сделать, нужно сначала загрузить фото, типа такого запроса:

```
$token = '3c30643586af83868a2c7b36b3fec07e66a36f284c480ef39404f49d42d22c8d6cba382a4633789d249c7';
$group_id = '162294758';
$album_id = '162294758';
$v = '5.64'; //версия vk api
$image_path = "http://worldwideshop.ru/vbot-dev/api/test.jpg"; //путь до картинки
$fp = fopen($image_path, 'r');

// получаем урл для загрузки
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getUploadServer?album_id=".$album_id."&group_id=".$group_id."&v=".$v."&access_token=".$token);
$url = json_decode($url)->response->upload_url;
print_r($url);

// отправка post картинки
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
print_r($result);

// сохраняем
$safe = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.save?server=".$result['server']."&photos_list=".$result['photos_list']."&album_id=".$result['aid']."&hash=".$result['hash']."&gid=".$group_id."&access_token=".$token);
$safe = json_decode($safe,true);
print_r($safe);
```

Результат:

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [error_code] => 5 [error_msg] => User
>   authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.
>   [request_params] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => oauth [value] => 1
>   ) [1](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_2) => Array ( [key] => method [value] => photos.save ) [2] => Array
>   ( [key] => server [value] => ) [3] => Array ( [key] => photos_list
>   [value] => ) [4] => Array ( [key] => album_id [value] => ) [5] =>
>   Array ( [key] => hash [value] => ) [6] => Array ( [key] => gid [value]
>   => 162294758 ) ) ) )

Вопросы:

- Где ошибка в моем коде или что не так?
- Куда правильно загружать это фото изначально? Если в альбом
  сообщества - он же должен быть публичным?
- Подскажите простой пример для загрузки attachment(в сети или готовые большие решения или старые неработающие частички кода, типа ссылок на git [тут](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_2)).

Comment: Нужно всего лишь использовать метод photos.getMessagesUploadServer

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении об ошибке сказано, что данную операцию невозможно сделать с авторизацеей сообщества!

> User authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth

Загружайте фотографии с авторизацией пользователя!

Comment: Очень даже возможно. https://vk.com/dev/photos.getMessagesUploadServer

Answer (score 0):

На `PHP` не пишу, но, возможно, подскажу

Все attachments должны быть оформлены так `<type><owner_id>_<media_id>`

Например `photo-54321_12345`. Это значит, что вложение есть фотография, принадлежащая группе `vk.com/club54321` и её идентификатор равен `12345`.

Все вложения идут через запятую, т.е. `photo-54321_12345,photo123_321`

Есть возможность, что вы всё таки не можете просто получить данные о своей фотографии

**P.S.**

Фотография может не дойти, даже при правильно оформленном `attachments`, если фотография не в публичном доступе (например, в скрытом альбоме)

Comment: Проверьте ещё права вашего токена, на всякий случай

Comment: Ой, 18 год, не туда я попал :)